# When I have git log print out as oneline, how do I reverse it?

Tags: git, bash

I have git log aliased to this:

```
git log --reverse --oneline --pretty=format:'-%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
```

But I want it to be reversed as well, as sometimes it's inconvenient to have the top needed to be scrolled to.

Comment: what do you mean? you **are** already reversing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `--reverse` out of the command you already have i.e.

```
git log --oneline --pretty=format:'-%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you for some reason want reverse it more times, so the

```
your_command | perl -e 'reverse <>'
```

can help ;)

or the

```
your_command | tail -r
```

or as @evnu suggest

```
your_command | tac
```

or when want reverese *each* line, you can

```
your_command | perl -nlE 'chomp;say scalar reverse'
```

especially the last is good, for example:

```
date | perl -nlE 'chomp;say scalar reverse'
```

prints

```
3102 TSEC 32:95:91 41 yaM euT
```

*ps: kidding only.. :)*

Comment: Or use `tac` (less characters than the above :))