# How to replace a number with sed command if number%7==0 in bash?

Tags: bash, sed, mathematical-expressions

I am trying to create a file that contains all numbers between 1 and 100, each number in a single line, but with all multiples of 7 substituted by 7:

```
...
12
13
7
15
16
...
```

My current code is the following, but the `sed` command does not work well,

```
$sudo seq 1 100 | sed -e 's/$?{%7==0}/7/g' > check.txt
```

How should I write math operations in `sed`?

Comment: you're redirecting seq's output to a file, nothing goes to sed

Comment: so i'll do sed before the output file- still not working. I edited. tnx!

Answer (score 3):

You can't do arithmetic operations in sed, but you can implement them to some extent with existing features, like:

```
seq 100 | sed '7~7s/.*/7/'
```

With awk that would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (i=1;i<=100;i++) print i%7?i:7 }'
```

Comment: thank you so much! if you can explain the expression '7~7s/.*/7/'  it will be great!

Comment: @riki it's easy, `7~7` means; beginning from seventh line, do the following for every seventh line; in this case the operation is `s/.*/7/`, which simply means replace the whole line with just 7.

Comment: WoW! great explanation. do u have an idea how can I cut with number delimiter? I mean- I want to write this way: ... | cut -d '[0-9]
but cut does not receive a regex as delimiter.

Comment: @riki  I didn't understand what you meant, could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: Probably useful to point out that notation like `7~7` is specific to GNU sed, and not portable to sed in other operating systems. (For example, macOS, FreeBSD, etc).

Comment: @ghoti exactly, the sed solution above is GNU-specific

Comment: @ oguz ismail : i mean that i want do display the second part of words: yyy2r, ttt3i and so on... i want from the number and right

Comment: @riki that's another question

Answer (score 1):

Sed can't do arithmetics, but Perl can. It can also do a sequence, so no need for `seq` and a pipe:

```
perl -le 'print $_ % 7 ? $_ : 7 for 1 .. 100'
```

It uses the [ternary operator](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Conditional-Operator) `?:` which evaluates the condition (`$_ % 7` here, i.e. the modulo) and returns the second parameter if it's true, or the third parameter otherwise. `-l` adds a newline to each `print`.

Answer (score 0):

[I love `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49613584/5825294), but I think this is more a job for `awk`:

```
seq 1 100 | awk '{ if ($1 % 7 == 0) { print 7; } else { print $0; } }'
```

Comment: If you're gonna use awk, why do you need seq at all?

Comment: Good point. Everything could be in a `for` loop in `BEGIN`/`END`. I just wanted to keep the source of the numbers separated. But maybe it doesn't even make sense, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Actually plain `bash` can handle this too:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100); do (( i % 7 )) && echo $i || echo 7; done
```

Comment: For a simple static example of numbers from 1 to 100, why not just go with `{1..100}` rather than spawning a subshell?